# Query taking too long to respond

Tags: mysql, sql

I have php list of items.

I am fetching a array from my sql database.

It was working ok but recently records are increasing and suddenly it is not showing records in list.

Suggest!

I have tried inner join which have less record for that is was working ok

query is:

```
  SELECT farmer.*, state.state_name, videos.video_url, employee.name AS nm 
      FROM farmer 
      LEFT JOIN state ON state.id = farmer.state 
      LEFT JOIN videos ON videos.farmer_id = farmer.id 
      LEFT JOIN employee ON farmer.employee_id = employee.id 
      WHERE farmer.is_deleted = 0 
      ORDER BY farmer.id DESC;
```

Comment: And it works on mysql CLI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To debug how this query is being executed by MySQL use `EXPLAIN`

- [Optimizing Queries with EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html)
- [EXPLAIN Output Format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html): This will help to you understand which columns ref are being used in Joins.

A simple solution to such problems would be the proper use of `indexes`.

- Based on the output of `EXPLAIN`, decide which `column ref` are being used while performing the join.
- Create an index on those columns, either separate indexes or composite one based on their behavior.

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON table_name (col_name);  -- for composite key you can mention multiple columns.
```

**How it helps**:

- Without an index, MySQL scans the complete table for each record of joining table to match a particular record.
- The index will help MySQL to directly access the desired record itself, which can drastically improve performance.

**Reference**:

- [Optimize Queries for Speed & Performance](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-optimize-mysql-queries-for-speed-and-perfor) - a quick guide with `explain` output and their explanation.
- For further query performance improvement, checkout [MySQL Performance Optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimization.html) section in the official documentation.

Comment: @RishikeshChavan, if this solves your problem, do accept and upvote the answer. :)